# creating a command for csv file creating in discord bot(python)

Tags: python, discord, bots

[codepython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ixdHH.jpg)

[codepython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OyFEF.jpg)

[codepython](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iksv.jpg)

Hey I´m trying to create a bot to add an command for creating a csv file about member names in the server, roles etc. I would also want to add a function to search from that file. Like if member joins to server again in a different name they could tell like !user I´m this person, and the bot would search from the list and possibly change the name, if the person is not in the list it would need to @administrator of the server. I would like to have help finding the information about creating this bot. So far i´ve managed to find something that did create the list of the members and thought how to make the commands from it. Help much appreciated.

```html
class Bot(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged in as {0}'.format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        # !users: Gathers the names of all users on the server and prints them to a CSV file
        if "!users" in message.content.lower():
            await message.channel.send("Getting user list...")
            users = self.get_all_members()

            with open('log.csv', 'w') as output:
                writer = csv.writer(output)
                writer.writerow(['Name'])
                for user in users:
                    writer.writerow([user.display_name])
                    
---------------------------------------------------------
@bot.command()
async def users(ctx):
# !users: Gathers the names of all users on the server and prints them to a CSV$
await ctx.send("Getting user list...")
await ctx.get_all_members()

with open('log.csv', 'w') as output:
        writer = csv.writer(output)
        writer.writerow(['Name'])
        for user in users:
            writer.writerow([user.display_name])

------------------------------------------------------------------

async def on_message(self, message):
# !users: Gathers the names of all users on the server and prints them to CSVS
        if "!users" in message.content.lower():
                await message.channel.send("Getting user list...")
                users = self.get_all_members()


                with open('log.csv', 'w') as output:
                writer = csv.writer(output)
                writer.writerow(['Name'])
                for user in users:
                writer.writerow([user.display_name])
```

Comment: Please consider posting your code as text and not images.

Answer (score -1):

Managed to find this from Youtube

```html
import csv

data=[]
with open("details.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
            data.append(row)
print (data)

name = input("Enter a first name: ")
#gives us a lis tof everuthing in col 0
col = [x[0] for x in data]

if name in col:
        for x in range(0, ien(data)):
            if name == data[x] [0]:
                print(data[x])
               
else:
    print("name doesn't exist")
```